# Reiteration of an analysis on resampled subgroups

Tags: permutation, resampling

I am new to this forum, so I will be very grateful for your help.

I have dataset with nested observations (2 individuals within 2922 pairs). What I need to do is to make a subgroups of the dataset which will include only one random member of a pair. However, I need to use both randomly selected individuals but also the group which lasted after the first group is selected. Next, I need to conduct an analysis on both groups.

And more, I have to reiterate this procedure (sampling > analysis) for let say 1000 times, and then summarize the results.

I was thinking about using
mstage(Data,stage=list("cluster","cluster"), varnames=list("pairno","indno"),
size=list(2922, c(rep(“1”,2922))), method=list("srswor","srswor"))

to select random memeber of each pair

and
!mstage(Data,stage=list("cluster","cluster"), varnames=list("pairno","twinno"),
size=list(2922, c(rep(“1”,2922))), method=list("srswor","srswor")) to get the rest of the group and save it

Next, I was wondering whether I can use e.g. foreach command or do command to repeat some code which will be using both samples. However, I don't know how to save the results for further analysis.

Did anybody have similar problem?
Thanks in advance!

I did not try anything before